# KotlinNullPointerException on menu item android

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, android-menu

I receive such error from Google Play console:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: my_package, PID: 19359
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at my_package.JobsList$getJobList$1.onResponse(JobsList.kt:286)
    at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$3wC8FyV4pyjrzrYL5U0mlYiviZw.run(Unknown Source:6)....
```

this error points on this line:

```
Singleton.menu!!.findItem(R.id.count)!!.isVisible = true
```

at method which makes api calls:

```
private fun getJobList(offset: Int, type: Int, token: String?, filterData: HashMap<String, String>, goTo: Boolean) {
        Singleton.filter_data = filterData
        Dispatcher().cancelAll()
        if (activity != null && isAdded) {
            Singleton.apiService().get_15_list("Bearer  $token", type, offset, filterData).enqueue(object : Callback<Last_15_jobs> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Last_15_jobs>, response: Response<Last_15_jobs>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val count = response.body()!!.count
                        if (context != null) {

                            setHasOptionsMenu(true)
                            if (Singleton.menu!=null){
                                Singleton.menu!!.findItem(R.id.count)!!.isVisible = true
                                Singleton.menu!!.findItem(R.id.write_message)!!.isVisible = false
                                Singleton.menu!!.findItem(R.id.filter)!!.isVisible = true
                                Singleton.menu!!.findItem(R.id.filter)!!.isEnabled = true
                            }


                            loading = false
                            refreshLayout.isRefreshing = false


                    } else {

                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Last_15_jobs>, t: Throwable) {

                }

            })
        }
    }
```

I thought that this line : `if (Singleton.menu!=null)` will solve that problem but it didn't. Maybe I have to check certain item? How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Use some null safety ?. Insyead !!

Comment: You're force-unwrapping the result of `findItem()` also - use '?' instead of '!!' to add null-safety, as it appears that those items are not being found.

Comment: Singleton.menu?.findItem(R.id.count)?.isVisible - smth like that?

Comment: What does Singleton class contains?

Comment: @NatigBabayev, what did you mean? It contains a lot od functions and vars which can be accessed from different places of the app

Comment: How do you initialize menu in that Singleton class?

Comment: yes of course)) I checked it at first)

Comment: Could you post initilization code for your Singleton class?

Comment: I get access to this class directly without initialisation